# Centos 6, php 5.6 (remi repo), installed gd and freetype, still missing function imagettftext

Tags: php, centos6

I am trying to install composer packages in PHP but get back that:

> xxx requires ext-imagettftext * -> the requested PHP extension
>   imagettftext is missing from your system.

I read in several posts that freetype and gd must be installed, but they are:

```
php -i | grep "FreeType"
FreeType Support => enabled
FreeType Linkage => with freetype
FreeType Version => 2.3.11

php -i | grep "GD "
GD Support => enabled
GD headers Version => 2.2.5
GD library Version => 2.2.5
```

I am using the REMI repo for PHP 5.6 and I am desperate to know what else I have to do to get *ext-imagettftext* working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any extension call **imagettftext**.

**imagettftext** is a function provided by the **gd** extension.

I think there is something wrong in the composer.json, should have "ext-gd"

```
$ php -r 'var_dump(function_exists("imagettftext"));'
bool(true)
```

Comment: After a night of research I did, you confirm my findings. The composer package that should be used has an unsatisfiable requirement, which is ext-imagettftext, an extension that does not exist.